# Does creating a token account on Solana make it rent free automatically?

Tags: solana

I have create a token on the devote and have created token account which I can transfer my token to successfully. I notice that a Solana fee is taken when I do this.

I also understand that I have to deposit enough Solana into an account to pay for rent or have 2 years worth of Solana to make it exempt.

When I create the account (using the code below) is it automatically making the accounts rent exempt or do I have to transfer additional Solana to do so.

How can I do this?

Code:

```
const tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  payer,
  mint,
  payer.publicKey
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All new accounts now require to be rent exempt cf https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#rent

So any accounts initialised successfully will be rent exempt. You don't have to worry about anything

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an associated token account created by this call will be rent exempt. You can see it in the `associated-token-program` [source code](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/48fbb5b7c49ea35848442bba470b89331dea2b2b/associated-token-account/program/src/processor.rs#L63).